# How can I add an if statement in my .tmpl file?

Tags: html, if-statement, templates

Below is my code:

JS:

```
func abc(){
    something = []
    return template = templatefunc(something: something)
}
```

.tmpl file:

```
<div>
    <div>{something}</div>
</div>
```

I want to add an if statement to {something} where if it is empty array, the div should not render, I tried

```
{if !empty(something)}
    {something}
{/if}
```

But this does not seem to work, how can I get this working? I don't want to use jQuery as my project does not allow it

Comment: Your code doesn't look like JavaScript, please add appropriate tags and context to your question, it doesn't seem answerable as it currently is.